# Has anyone had to DM the Giant Coral Snake from 5e SaltMarsh dealing stun damage to undead?

Tags: dnd-5e, undead, ghosts-of-saltmarsh

Last night I was DMing my group. They were fighting some undead and the Wizard polymorphed the ranger's animal companion into the Giant Coral Snake from Ghosts of Saltmarsh (page 236):

Upon a hit by the coral snake, the target must make a DC 12 CON save or be stunned until its next turn. Furthermore, on a failed save the target begins to hallucinate and is affected by short term madness. This lasts for 10 minutes.

Ok, so that's pretty clear. However, since the coral snake was attacking an undead creature I ruled the stun feature, as well as the hallucination, wouldn't take affect due to Undead creatures being immune to poison (or, in this case venom from a coral snake).

The stat block didn't call it poison damage but....well, it had to have been right? My players seemed to accept this line of reasoning but I am curious, has anyone else encountered this?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your question is. Are you asking if the stun from the coral snake is poison damage?

Comment: Do you ask if your ruling was "right" or "wrong"? I guess you ask the wrong person in the first place. It was your game, not ours.

Comment: My question was more “has anyone else encountered this and how did you handle it”?

Comment: That's kind of an opinion based question. If you're asking about mechanics of its attack, that's one thing, but just asking about how others have used is more like a discussion which fits better in forums.

Comment: This is a pretty specific scenario and it's possible that nobody has encountered it before. But I'm betting that plenty of DMs have encountered a situation where there seemed to be a conflict between an ability/effect normally meant for living creatures being applied to undead. Your question might get more/better answers if you ask it in a way that is a little more universally applicable.

Comment: I’m pretty sure the question the OP asks is not the one he wants answered - “Has anyone considered ...?”, “Yes, you have”. What do you really want from us?

Comment: @Rykara I'm gonna slightly disagree. It being a specific scenario is generally better, it makes it easier to make the question well focused. The problem, as I see it, is that it doesn't focus on solving any problem. northerndawg, are you asking what the rules work on the matter, or on how one can best handle this kind of situation (which there may be a workable version of)? The current version suggests you just want to chat with others about this, for which this site is not the best fit. For that you'd be better of with a [forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/52137), or our [chat].